# How to select specific object property into a string array (in a single action)

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Say I have some array of objects

```
[
    {
        "Property": "1"
    },
    {
        "Property": "2"
    },
    {
        "Property": "3"
    }
]
```

I want to select just `Property` so I end up with a string array, so I can later call `join()` on it

```
[
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"   
]
```

I tried using the Select action, but it asks me to map to a property, so I just end up with yet another object array:

[image]

I guess I could initialise a string and the loop around the array, appending the property each time, but is there a way of doing this in a single action?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Select Data operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations?tabs=consumption#select-action), and Switch the view. See below.

In order to only get an array with value types, you should first click on the switch button at the right side of the action.

[image: Switch button]

Add your property, in your case that would be `item()?['Property']`.

[image: Add the property]
[image: Result after saving]

**Result output**
In a run this would result in an array with plain string values.

[image: Result output]

After this, you can join the array the way you already had in mind, with the join function.

Comment: This answer saves my day.  Awesome solution @Dennis Rosenbaum

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Parse JSON` for this. Here is my logic app

[image]

> I guess I could initialise a string and the loop around the array, appending the property each time, but is there a way of doing this in a single action?

Like you have mentioned you can use `outputs('Compose')?['Property']` to fetch the property.

[image]